# How to draw a circle in an Android native application activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I am new to android. I am trying to draw a circle in my android activity. First of all is that possible in android activity ?

While googling, I found that need to add canvas for this. Is that a plugin ? How to include this in my application? I tried to draw programically. So I tried the following code. But doesn't working.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int r = 4;
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mCanvas.drawCircle(x,y,r,mPaint); 
}
```

I am new to this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
int r = 4;
Paint mPaint = new Paint(); 

public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.drawCircle(x,y,r,mPaint); 
}
```

Comment: Create Coustem View And Use OnDraw Methed and Create The Object of This Coustem View Class

Comment: use This Codehttp://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/01/custom-view-example-in-android.html

Comment: showing Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist.

Comment: http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/04/draw-circle-on-canvas-canvasdrawcirclet.html